# Dell Switches and Spanning-Tree Route ID Configuration

Tags: mac, bridge, root, spanning-tree

I am analyzing a network for a colleague. It's a fairly simple topology and all the switches have converged on a common root-bridge, however two of the non-root bridges have identified the root as the MAC address of the root-bridge, whereras all the other bridges have identified the root as the MAC address of the root-bridge preceded by a 2 byte value (e.g., 10:00). Can someone please explain what might be going on? I have looked extensively both on the Internet and also Dell's support site but I have not been able to find any articles addressing this particular issue.

Thank you